# Why aren’t my spoiler markup working?

Tags: support, markdown

On [Recognizable natural numbers for alien message?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/70227) I used `>!` at the beginning of a paragraph in 3 places.  Only 1 of them works! What's the problem?  I went over it carefully for stray spaces, and see no difference between what works and what doesn't, or what the help states.

Answer (score 1):

James K fixed it, and explains in the edit comment that two *consecutive* spoiler blocks don’t work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like it's working fine, **but**

- Multiple `>!` spoiler blocks are joined into one paragraph
- You must start *each* new line with `>!`

Markdown quoting (which is what spoiler blocks really are a special case of) is funny like that.

I guess if you really want them separate you can add a dummy paragraph in between them. I've been known to add a simple "and" between quoted blocks where they are actually distinct.

Comment: I don’t understand.  Each line (flowed para) does have a `>! ` but it shows as a regular blockquote with `!` in it.  They are discontiguous, with non-hidden between them. What do you mean by a dummy *and* paragraph?